# Content Delivery Security

Tags: tls, web-application, access-control, random

An application has 2 servers - `Server1` and `Server2`.

`Server1` stores db and image+video files. `Server2` stores a copy of all image+video files.

According to the geographical location of a user, if appropriate, sometimes `Server2` is used (instead of `Server1`) for delivery of content.

The application has image and video files which are private to users. All logic of who is allowed to access which file resides in the db in `Server1`.

Only users logged in the application (with username and password) can access (their) private content.

The way I intend to serve content is -

1. Image (or video) request comes to `Server1`. It is checked whether
   this user can access the file. If yes, then -
2. (If geographically appropriate) `Server1` sends CORS headers (for `Server2`) + 3 10 digit random numbers (`numset`) as headers, and the response is redirected to `Server2`.
3. Regarding `numset` - `Server1` conveys a new set of 3 10 digit random numbers to `Server2` every 30 seconds. Each set of 3 10 digit random numbers has a life of 40 seconds (10 seconds more to prevent rejection of inflight requests).
4. Redirected request reaches `Server2`, where request headers are checked against already existing `numset`, and CORS request origin is checked to match that of `Server1`. If all checks are ok, then -
5. File is served.

Note: 
1. image and video file names themselves are 8 digit random numbers. 
2. `Server1` and `Server2` are both over https.

Questions - 
1. How can `Server2` be made more secure, so that a logged in user, who is actually a hacker, making curl requests, cannot access files which he is not authorized to view? 
2. Is this approach appropriate from a performance point of view?

Comment: Why not simply create a ticket with information such as a timestamp, user ID, originating IP, etc., the whole authenticated using a HMAC and include all this either in the URL or in a cookie? This way the two servers would not have to communicate, server2 would just have to check the HMAC to check the ticket validity.

Comment: Ok, lets say I use JWT based authentication between `Server1` and `Server2`, which is  also stateless. But the problem remains, if an authenticated users is a hacker. His hacking attempts to `Server2` (to get media files), will seem like legit requests and he can, possibly, brute-force his way to access files which he is not authorized to view!

Comment: Hence the necessity of choosing a strong secret to protect your tokens. As soon as a brute-force is expected to last a few thousands of years, it will most likely not be attempted and the attacker will choose another, more practical way to get into your system (in other words this will no be the weakest point in your security).